# Can I add more than one value in default in SQL

Tags: sql, default

```
create table if not exists addresstype
(
    addtype_ID char(1) default ('r','b','p'),
    add_type char(15),
    primary key(addtype_id)

) engine=innodb;
```

I am trying to create a table with more than one value in default. Is that possible?

Comment: What would it mean for there to be more than one value in default? Are you trying to limit the possible values of the `addtype_ID` column?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking.   Do you mean one default for the same key, or different defaults for different keys?

Comment: Sounds like you need a `Check Constraint` not a default.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. The default is what the column's value would be if no value is specified for that column during an `insert`. Without a default, such columns would be 'null'.

If you  had more than one default, how would the server know which one to choose in any given situation?